# Удаление непечатаемыемых специальных символов и знаков из слов через regex

Tags: регулярные-выражения, анализ-данных

Есть текст, например:

Twenty-five years have passed since the 1991 incident in which Indian army soldiers allegedly raped between 23 and 100 women in Kashmir2"!s Kunan and Poshpora villages during a search operation.

но в нём есть неотображаемые символы. Как с помощью регулярных выражений написать правило для re, чтобы удалить эти символы. Эти символы могут быть как внутри слова, так и просто отдельно от них. Стандартный `re.sub(r'\W', ' ', str(X[sen]))` не избавляет от них. Код символов что-то около `x04`.

З.Ы. Конечно при опубликовании эти символы не видно, представьте, что в слове "Kashmir2" перед двойкой в текстовом редакторе несколько квадратиков написано :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В регулярках есть выражениe, чтобы искать 8-ми битные коды.

> Код символов что-то около x04

Если у вас только этот код, то убрать его можно через `\x04`.

Если их больше, то можно написать выражение для поиска всех нечитаемых символов через диапазоны:

- `[\x00-\x1F\x7F-\xFF]` — убрать все символы в диапазонах 0-31, 127-255
  соответствует **7 bit ASCII**
- `[\x00-\x1F\x7F]` — убрать все символы в диапазоне 0-31 и 127-ой
  соответствует **8 bit ASCII**
- `[\x00-\x1F\x7F\xA0]/u` — для **UTF-8**

Подробнее [здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1176904/how-to-remove-all-non-printable-characters-in-a-string) на английском stack overflow.

В Вашем конкретном случае подойдёт любой из представленных вариантов.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: @VortexPlay ясно. Тогда можно попробовать `x[0-9a-f][0-9a-f]`, но сами понимаете, что слова вроде **axed** обрежутся до **а**. В каком ЯП считываете, **Pyhon**? В **Ruby** всё очень удобно с кодировками и необычными символами, плюс в нём регулярные выражения встроены в синтаксис.

Comment: Проблема решена, оказывается у меня было регулярное выражение, которое удаляло бэкслеши, поэтому сначала Ваш вариант не работал. Теперь всё работает, как Вы и описали, спасибо